# Probability Tree Hide Nodes Hide randomly

Tags: probability

I am creating a probability tree diagram such as

```
       1
     /   \
   .4    .6
  / \    / \
.2  .2 .2  .4
```

The number of nodes and size of the splits is generated randomly based on some conditions.

Now I want to hide the value of some of the nodes. I want to show some and I want the user to find the rest. How can I achieve this? Is there any logic/algorithm to determine this? The logic should work regardless of the size of the tree.  For example, the above could become

```
       ?
     /   \
   .4     ?
  / \    / \
 ?  .2  ?  .4
```

I am looking for any predefined algorithm for node value hiding logic in a probability tree.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding this. Can you please try rewording it? Specifically, what "few nodes" are you referring to? The sentence that begins "I want to show" also doesn't make sense to me. Also, by a number for each node, do you mean a weight associated to it? By splitting these numbers, do you  mean that the numbers associated to adjacent nodes are somehow related?

Comment: @AndrewKelley i Posted the exact scenario here in my another post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901853/algorithm-for-probablity-tree-conditional-visiblity?noredirect=1#comment36803229_23901853

Comment: I don't think that link works anymore. (Clicking it doesn't work. I also googled your question number and the link Google provided also doesn't work.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want users to be able to solve for the missing values at level $L-1$, where $L$ is the length of the tree, you can only hide at most $1$ child node of each of the parent nodes on level $L-1$. If that is the case, your algorithm is simple and just generates for each node $i$ at level $L$ a uniform random variable between $1$ and $N(i)$, where $N(i)$ is the number of child nodes of $i$, and hides the corresponding child.

Comment: In the example, showing any three of the four leaf values would determine the entire tree, allowing you to remove both children of the root.

Comment: @Teepeemm I don't disagree. My answer was meant to refer to the last level of the tree - I have made this more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the entire tree.  In each row, remove one of each pair of leaves (chosen arbitrarily).  Remove the root (assuming you specify that the tree is a probability tree).  Now, whenever a value has an unknown as its child, you can switch which is unknown.  Repeat this process until you get bored.

This will give a tree that can be solved to find the original tree.  I can’t prove that all such solvable trees can be made this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this recursively with the following procedure:

There are two kinds of nodes: 'bottom up' (B) and 'top down' (T) nodes. B nodes should be calculated by adding up values of their children or their value is shown. T nodes should be calculated as the value of their parent minus the value of their sibling. The root node is a T node, since its value is known to be $1$, but still can be hidden.

For each B node, decide whether or not its value will be shown. If it is shown, make one child a T node and one child a B node. Else, make both childs B nodes. (If B has no children, its value must be shown.)

For each T node, do not show its value. Make one child a T node and one child a B node. If the node has no children, hide its value.